# Voice recognition not working as a service when Google Search version > 2.2.10.573038

Tags: android, voice-recognition

Some friends and I have been working in an app that requires to have a service running listening for voice commands. We have successfully implemented the listener. However, after we started having problems because the operating system killed the service after a while (I suppose to reclaim some resources). We (apparently) fixed this problem by making the service a foreground process (calling startForeground).

We have been testing the app in a range of devices and we found out that the app was still being killed by the OS in some devices. Having a close look at this issue we found out that the devices where the app is being killed have Google Search version greater or equal to 2.3... (for instance  2.4.10.626027) If we uninstall the updates and downgrade to version  2.2.10.573038 then it works like a charm.

By the way, I have mentioned Google Search here because when we start the voice listener, a package named com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox is started.

Does anyone have an idea of why this might be? or what main differences exist between the versions 2.2.10.573038 (and older) and those after? Of course the solution would be to downgrade the version but we would like it to be compatible with the newer versions too...

Comment: Another solution to consider would be just to use another engine like [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net) in either local or network mode to look for the words. The open source will give you flexibility to implement the things you need, not creating the hacks around unsupported functionality.